# PHPFarm with jpeg integration

Tags: php, jpeg, php5

So I'm attempting to get phpfarm up and running, but for some reason can't get jpeg support from gd to work... Here are my config options

```
configoptions="\
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-memory-limit \
--with-regex=php \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sqlite-utf8 \
--enable-wddx \
--with-xsl=/usr \
--with-zip \
--with-zlib \
--enable-zip \
--with-mysql=/usr \
--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config \
--enable-pdo \
--with-pdo-mysql=/usr \
--enable-fastcgi \
--enable-force-cgi-redirect \
--with-openssl \
--with-zlib \
--with-gettext \
--with-curl \
--with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-mcrypt \
"
```

I've already created symlinks for my jpeg directory in the /usr/lib directory:

```
#lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root           36 Nov  3 14:22 libjpeg.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
```

And I compile (php 5.3.29) and each time I don't see JPEG support. The odd thing is that if I change the gd option to

```
--with-gd=shared
```

I no longer get 'imagecreatefromjpeg function does not exist' but instead I get the php execution completely failing and exiting when trying to process the first jpeg image.

Additionally, I've tried adding the following with no success:

```
--with-libdir=lib \
```

Anyone have any ideas? I can't seem to find anyway around this.

Note: If I disable phpfarm and use the native php (version 5.3.10) then everything works perfectly (jpegs work like a charm)

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same issue for some time now and i finally found the solution.

I use Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and have compiled php 5.4.31 with the following options:

```
configoptions="\
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-pcntl \
--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-wddx \
--enable-zip \
--with-libdir=lib/i386-linux-gnu \
--with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--with-curl \
--with-mysql \
--with-pdo_mysql \
--with-openssl \
--enable-xml \
--with-zlib \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-gettext \
--enable-zip \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2/freetype \
--with-t1lib \
```

GD was enabled, but JPEG support was not, even after i tried numerous suggestions on other fora.

The solution was very simple:

1. go to the source directory: cd /opt/phpfarm/src/php-5.4.31
2. make clean
3. cd ..
4. ./compile.sh 5.4.31
5. Party :)

This worked for me, hope it works for you!